# Error while trying to restore a savedInstance - Android

Tags: android

I'm having the following problem while trying to restore a ProgressDialog from a configuration change. This is my code:

`server` is a class that does some networking in a thread and after it finishes, it calls the callback on the handler that made the initial call.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private boolean hasAuthDialog = false;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    // login fragment
    public void doLogin(View b) {
        boolean ok = true;
        if(ok) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Autenticando");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            hasAuthDialog = true;
            try {
                server.doLogin(cedula.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString(), new ServerBridgeResponse_CallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(Boolean success, Object... args) {
                        // login finalizado
                        if(success) {
                            Toast.makeText(me, "Login success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(me, "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        hasAuthDialog = false;
                    }
                });
            } catch (ServerBridgeNotReadyException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("hasAuthDialog", hasAuthDialog);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    hasAuthDialog = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasAuthDialog");
    if(hasAuthDialog) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Autenticando restored");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        hasAuthDialog = true;
    }
}
```

The thing is that after an orientation change, when debugging, `progressDialog` in the `doLogin` method still refers to the old dialog and not the new one that I created in `onRestoreInstance` (I know this because of the message. It still says 'Autenticando' instead of 'Autenticando Restored'). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your `onCreate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried making progressDialog static? That way the set variable will be dismissed by the run method, and not the reference to the old progressDialog.

Answer (score 1):

I get it now. The thing is that when there's an orientation change, Android creates an entirely new instance of the activity. Because of this behavior, the keyword `this` in the callback refers to the previous instance.

One way we could fix this problem is by making the `progressDialog` static as suggested by *Bassiuz*, but one different (and IMO more flexible) solution would be to create an `static MainActivity me` variable and assigning it `this` at the end of `onCreate`. After that, in `doLogin` callback, use `me.progressDialog` and it should have the reference to the new dialog.

Thanks to *Bassiuz*!